# Python Tkinter - Overwriting/Deleting "Default" Widget Bindings

Tags: python, binding, tkinter

I'm using a Tkinter Text box in my Python (using 2.7.2) script as an entry-type box -- when enter is pressed, it copies the contents into a different text box and then deletes it out of the entry one.

I've bound the necessary event to the Text box when the Enter key is pressed.

The only problem I have is that whenever I hit the Enter key, it seems to execute my event and *then* the widgets "default" binding: adding a newline. I'm not sure of a way to either delete the newline after it is added, or simply get rid of the widgets default binding.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [python gui events out of order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458026/python-gui-events-out-of-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variations of this question have been asked before. The short answer is "do a `return "break"` in the code executed by your binding.

I gave a much longer answer here: [python gui events out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458026/python-gui-events-out-of-order/2472992#2472992)

Answer (score 0):

Returning `'break'` at the end of your event handler will interrupt event propagation.