# Python Tkinter Listbox event curselection() trails selection value

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, listbox, mouseevent

I am programming a GUI using a Listbox as a file selection pane. Originally I was using `<Double-1>` as my event trigger, but decided to switch to `<Button-1>`. Long story short, I find there is a difference in how they process. `<Button-1>` event requires 2 clicks for lb.curselection() to be accurate; whereas `<Double-1>` works as expected.

Why does it do this and/or is this a bug in Tkinter?
Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.root)
        self.lb.pack(side="left")

        for i in range(10):
            self.lb.insert("end", f"Value {i}")
        
        self.lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.gui_dblClick_event)


    def gui_dblClick_event(self, event):
        print(self.lb.curselection())


    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rootWin = GUI()
    rootWin.mainloop()
```

**`<Double-1>` Output: [imgur](https://imgur.com/V0Nr7oQ)**

- "Value 0" - (0,)
- "value 1" - (1,)
- "value 2" - (2,)
- "Value 3" - (3,)

**`<Button-1>` Output: [imgur](https://imgur.com/sKH8U5F)**

- "Value 0" - ( )
- "Value 1" - (0,)
- "Value 2" - (1,)
- "Value 3" - (2,)

`<Button-1>` Double Click is where this becomes very clear.

**`<Button-1>` Double Click Output: [imgur](https://imgur.com/8frhO6X)**

- "Value 0" - ( )
- "Value 0" - (0,)
- "Value 1" - (0,)
- "Value 1" - (1,)
- "Value 2" - (1,)
- "Value 2" - (2,)

Comment: The selection is done in the default handler which is executed after `<Button-1>` callback.

Comment: As acw1668 mentions, this probably has to do with the event order, check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458026/python-gui-events-out-of-order/2472992#2472992) for more information.

Comment: @acw1668 Indeed. Due to this, even on Button-1 events, shouldn't the curselection() be a proper index value for the current selection? I have to Double Click a Single Click event to get an accurate index position.

Comment: You can bind on the virtual event `<<ListboxSelect>>` instead of `<Button-1>`.

Comment: @fhdrsdg Thank you. That is a good reference to have. Book marked for sure.

Comment: @acw1668 I have continued experimenting with <<ListboxSelect>> and bindtags. I appreciate your suggestion. However, I don't believe the issue is in order of execution with bind tags. I have juggled order of defined bindtags, but still have one trailing widget handle, after a class level event is focused, then all following class level handles won't call my widget level handle.

Comment: I have resolved my issue with <ButtonRelease-1> as described here: https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm. But will update if I find depth of the issue.